# Why value of a is 1?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, command-substitution

I'm learning shell scripting and I am writing a script which lists the file for which the user has "7" permission, i.e. "rwx". So far I've written this:

```bsh
for F in *
do
        a= $(stat -c "%a" "$F")
        echo $a
        if ((b==7))
        then
                echo $F
        fi
done
```

Here the value of a is "1". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

In shell, spaces matter.  Replace

```
a= $(stat -c "%a" "$F")
```

With:

```
a=$(stat -c "%a" -- "$F")
```

(also adding the `--` option delimiter so the command still works for file names that start with `-`)

or

```
a=$(stat -Lc "%a" -- "$F")
```

if for symlinks, you want the permissions of the target of the symlink (since on most systems, the permissions of the symlink itself are not relevant).

#### Example

To make things simple, let's just run the `stat` command on a single file and we'll do it at the interactive command line:

```
$ stat -c "%a" file
660
```

Now, let's try the command with the space:

```
$ a= $(stat -c "%a" file)
bash: 660: command not found
$ echo a=$a
a=
```

We get an error message and `a` is not set to a new value.  (If, as in your case, `a` had previously been assigned to `1`, it would stay unchanged at `1`.)  Now try without spaces:

```
$ a=$(stat -c "%a" file)
$ echo a=$a
a=660
```

This works.  `a` is successfully set to the number returned by the `stat` command.